# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer?

Tags: ruby

I can't seem to find what is causing this bug. The server is saying that it is line #8 in this code:

```
  class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create 
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params [:session][:password])
       log_in user
       redirect_to user     
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space here:

```
if user && user.authenticate(params [:session][:password])
# see?
params [:session][:password]
```

Fix it to `params[:session][:password]` and re-try

Comment: To complement the answer,  because of the space pointed out,  `[:session]` is interpreted as an array literal, and `[:password]` is interpreted as `Array#[]` method call, which expects an integer argument, but the OP is passing a symbol `:password`.

Comment: Presumably because it interprets this as a method call with a single argument of a list literal (`[:session]`) indexed by a symbol (`[:password]`)?

Comment: sorry, commented before your post showed up.

Comment: I guess I really don't know enough yet to know exactly why this happens in the array. Even though you explained it I still don't really understand. I'm in chapter 8 of Rails Tutorial and that is most of my exposure so far.